# Automatically retrieve google books Bibtex citation matching ISBN

Tags: unix, google-books

I would like to retrieve automatically, and reliably, the bibtex file which I can manually download at google books, for a book identified by its ISBN. The purpose is to create a citation database for a list of books given by their ISBN. I am working on linux operating systems and I am especially open to any solution using scripting languages such as java, perl python or shell scripts. Primarily I am interested to know if there are existing solutions or almost solutions for this problem which I could adapt easily. A related question can be found here: [Automating book citation search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217992/automating-book-citation-search)  but it is a little older and links are dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this project https://github.com/xlcnd/isbntools.

The command `isbn_meta 978...` retrieves the metadata for the book, however **not** in *bibtex* format (but it is easy to use the output and transform it to *bibtex*).

Anyway in the next major release I am planning (yes I am the creator and maintainer of the project) to add more format options to the output, **including bibtex**.

Comment: Great! On ubuntu I had to `sudo apt-get install python-pip` and `sudo pip install isbntools` in order to run `isbn_meta`. Don't know if this is the intended way to do it.

Comment: For some isbn's I get a `CRITICAL:isbntools.dev.webservice:ISBNToolsHTTPError for https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn+0471922870&fields=items/volumeInfo(title,authors,publisher,publishedDate,language)&maxResults=1 with code 403`

Comment: Google Books doesn't have a register for that book as you can see directly by going to https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn+0471922870&fields=items/volum‌​eInfo(title,authors,publisher,publishedDate,language)&maxResults=1 directly in the browser. World Catalog is more complete!

Comment: In some LINUX systems you have to precede the `pip install` command with `sudo` (you are alert to that in the README file!).

Comment: Ok, the sudo is obvious for me. The extensions of the README files confused me. I more or less guessed the install routine. Is this python standard?

Comment: Yes, this is the standard practice! You could read the READMEs here: [rst](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isbntools) [md](https://github.com/xlcnd/isbntools)

Comment: Nice project. I wondered yesterday if it would be strait-forward to modify the scripts such that it can search also for authors or titles. It seems to be obvious how to construct the googleapis urls at least. But maybe it is less trivial than I think.

Comment: It is easy! Build a new script emulating for example `goob.py` and pass the appropriate url. However you need to choose the right selector in the response... By the way, release 3 is out, with support for BibTeX, EndNote, RefWorks and Microsoft Word bibliographic formats.

Comment: Great! It is not yet obvious for me how to modify the script, mainly because the relation between the files in the package is not obvious to me. Since this is beyond the present question I created a new one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960956/adopt-isbntools-to-search-for-keywords-in-author-and-title?noredirect=1#comment35057155_22960956. Maybe you want to expand a bit on it.