# Adapt isbntools to search for keywords in author and title

Tags: python, bibliography

The python package 'isbntools' (https://github.com/xlcnd/isbntools) allows to retrieve bibliography information about books from online resources. In particular the script `isbn_meta [number]` retrieves information about the book with given isbn-number `[number]`. Among other it uses data from google using googleapis as `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn+[number]&fields=`. It is obvious that the url can be adjusted to search e.g. for a general `[keyword]` `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=[keyword]`. But how can I reuse the code in 'isbntools' to create a script, say `title_meta` which searches and retrieves bibliography data based on `[keyword]`. My problem is to some extent that it is not obvious for me how to deal consistently with the python package.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Can't you inherit the class in your custom one and reuse that?

Comment: Probably, but how? It's possibly obvious for a python programmer. The question was raised here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001907/automatically-retrieve-google-books-bibtex-citation-matching-isbn/22881516?noredirect=1#comment35021850_22881516 in the comments to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 3.0.1 exists a new script `isbn_goom` which uses [goom.py](https://github.com/xlcnd/isbntools/blob/master/isbntools/dev/goom.py) that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: This is just an example, not meant to be used as is.

You can override the variable that contains the URL in this way, when you want:

```
import goob

goob.SERVICE_URL = 'my_new_googleapis_url'

myquery = goob.query(myKeyword)
```

Notice that you will need an `%s` in the `SERVICE_URL` variable on the place you want to put your keyword.